# Doesn't the verbatim environment work with the standalone class?

Tags: verbatim, standalone

I have the following code, which is as minimal as it could possibly be ( standalone 2015/07/15 v1.2):

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{verbatim}
Ciao
\end{verbatim}
\end{document}
```

And I get the error:

```
! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.
```

If I replace the `standalone` class with another class, e.g. `article`, everything works fine.

Where's the issue?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try

```
\documentclass[preview]{standalone}% <-- added option "preview"

\begin{document}
\begin{verbatim}
Ciao
\end{verbatim}
\end{document}
```

This should work ...

**Edit:** Also work with option `varwidth`. Both options enable to show verbatim environments and as well as displayed math. This is not special described in `standalone` manual, but seems that for text elements/environments, which normally occupy whole text line, it is obligatory to select appropriate standalone's options.

Comment: Care to explain why is an optional argument mandatory?

Comment: @Matsmath, done.

Answer (score 3):

The `verbatimbox` package allows inline verbatim environments that work directly with the `standalone` class.  Once the box is created with the `verbbox` environment, it is displayed with `\theverbbox`.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{verbatimbox}
\begin{document}
\begin{verbbox}
Ciao
\end{verbbox}
\theverbbox
\end{document}
```

[image]

Example 2 (longer code and optional argument):

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{verbatimbox}
\begin{document}
\begin{verbbox}[\scshape]
This is code line 1
Blah
Blah-blah
Finis
\end{verbbox}
\theverbbox
\end{document}
```

[image]