# Standalone with verbatim - highlighting code with pygments

Tags: pdftex, standalone, syntax-highlighting, pygments

### Issue: The width of the generated pdf does not match the width of the code

The Python package [Pygments](https://pygments.org) is used to generate a syntactically highlighted code in LaTeX format.

As an example, the input file is `hello.cpp` and the output file produced by Pygments is `hello.tex`. After changing from `article` to the `standalone` class, the file is further processed with `pdflatex` and a pdf file is generated. (The python code used for this example is provided at the end of this post)

[image: Workflow generating a pdf with pygments]

The width of the generated pdf does not match the width of the code! There is too much white-space.

Is it possible to get `pdflatex` to automatically adjust the width of the generated pdf to fit the code, but no more, in the source file?

The LaTeX file generated by pygments, i.e. `hello.tex`, is rather long, listed below. When compiled with `pdflatex hello.tex` the generated pdf is much wider than the code.

```latex
\documentclass[preview]{standalone}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}



\makeatletter
\def\PY@reset{\let\PY@it=\relax \let\PY@bf=\relax%
    \let\PY@ul=\relax \let\PY@tc=\relax%
    \let\PY@bc=\relax \let\PY@ff=\relax}
\def\PY@tok#1{\csname PY@tok@#1\endcsname}
\def\PY@toks#1+{\ifx\relax#1\empty\else%
    \PY@tok{#1}\expandafter\PY@toks\fi}
\def\PY@do#1{\PY@bc{\PY@tc{\PY@ul{%
    \PY@it{\PY@bf{\PY@ff{#1}}}}}}}
\def\PY#1#2{\PY@reset\PY@toks#1+\relax+\PY@do{#2}}

\@namedef{PY@tok@w}{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.73,0.73,0.73}{##1}}}
\@namedef{PY@tok@c}{\let\PY@it=\textit\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.25,0.50,0.50}{##1}}}
\@namedef{PY@tok@cp}{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.74,0.48,0.00}{##1}}}
\@namedef{PY@tok@k}{\let\PY@bf=\textbf\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.50,0.00}{##1}}}
\@namedef{PY@tok@kp}{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.50,0.00}{##1}}}
\@namedef{PY@tok@kt}{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.69,0.00,0.25}{##1}}}
\@namedef{PY@tok@o}{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.40,0.40,0.40}{##1}}}
\@namedef{PY@tok@ow}{\let\PY@bf=\textbf\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.67,0.13,1.00}{##1}}}
\@namedef{PY@tok@nb}{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.50,0.00}{##1}}}
\@namedef{PY@tok@nf}{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.00,1.00}{##1}}}
\@namedef{PY@tok@nc}{\let\PY@bf=\textbf\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.00,1.00}{##1}}}
\@namedef{PY@tok@nn}{\let\PY@bf=\textbf\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.00,1.00}{##1}}}
\@namedef{PY@tok@ne}{\let\PY@bf=\textbf\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.82,0.25,0.23}{##1}}}
\@namedef{PY@tok@nv}{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.10,0.09,0.49}{##1}}}
\@namedef{PY@tok@no}{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.53,0.00,0.00}{##1}}}
\@namedef{PY@tok@nl}{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.63,0.63,0.00}{##1}}}
\@namedef{PY@tok@ni}{\let\PY@bf=\textbf\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.60,0.60,0.60}{##1}}}
\@namedef{PY@tok@na}{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.49,0.56,0.16}{##1}}}
\@namedef{PY@tok@nt}{\let\PY@bf=\textbf\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.50,0.00}{##1}}}
\@namedef{PY@tok@nd}{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.67,0.13,1.00}{##1}}}
\@namedef{PY@tok@s}{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.73,0.13,0.13}{##1}}}
\@namedef{PY@tok@sd}{\let\PY@it=\textit\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.73,0.13,0.13}{##1}}}
\@namedef{PY@tok@si}{\let\PY@bf=\textbf\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.73,0.40,0.53}{##1}}}
\@namedef{PY@tok@se}{\let\PY@bf=\textbf\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.73,0.40,0.13}{##1}}}
\@namedef{PY@tok@sr}{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.73,0.40,0.53}{##1}}}
\@namedef{PY@tok@ss}{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.10,0.09,0.49}{##1}}}
\@namedef{PY@tok@sx}{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.50,0.00}{##1}}}
\@namedef{PY@tok@m}{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.40,0.40,0.40}{##1}}}
\@namedef{PY@tok@gh}{\let\PY@bf=\textbf\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.00,0.50}{##1}}}
\@namedef{PY@tok@gu}{\let\PY@bf=\textbf\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.50,0.00,0.50}{##1}}}
\@namedef{PY@tok@gd}{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.63,0.00,0.00}{##1}}}
\@namedef{PY@tok@gi}{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.63,0.00}{##1}}}
\@namedef{PY@tok@gr}{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{1.00,0.00,0.00}{##1}}}
\@namedef{PY@tok@ge}{\let\PY@it=\textit}
\@namedef{PY@tok@gs}{\let\PY@bf=\textbf}
\@namedef{PY@tok@gp}{\let\PY@bf=\textbf\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.00,0.50}{##1}}}
\@namedef{PY@tok@go}{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.53,0.53,0.53}{##1}}}
\@namedef{PY@tok@gt}{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.27,0.87}{##1}}}
\@namedef{PY@tok@err}{\def\PY@bc##1{{\setlength{\fboxsep}{-\fboxrule}\fcolorbox[rgb]{1.00,0.00,0.00}{1,1,1}{\strut ##1}}}}
\@namedef{PY@tok@kc}{\let\PY@bf=\textbf\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.50,0.00}{##1}}}
\@namedef{PY@tok@kd}{\let\PY@bf=\textbf\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.50,0.00}{##1}}}
\@namedef{PY@tok@kn}{\let\PY@bf=\textbf\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.50,0.00}{##1}}}
\@namedef{PY@tok@kr}{\let\PY@bf=\textbf\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.50,0.00}{##1}}}
\@namedef{PY@tok@bp}{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.50,0.00}{##1}}}
\@namedef{PY@tok@fm}{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.00,0.00,1.00}{##1}}}
\@namedef{PY@tok@vc}{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.10,0.09,0.49}{##1}}}
\@namedef{PY@tok@vg}{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.10,0.09,0.49}{##1}}}
\@namedef{PY@tok@vi}{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.10,0.09,0.49}{##1}}}
\@namedef{PY@tok@vm}{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.10,0.09,0.49}{##1}}}
\@namedef{PY@tok@sa}{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.73,0.13,0.13}{##1}}}
\@namedef{PY@tok@sb}{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.73,0.13,0.13}{##1}}}
\@namedef{PY@tok@sc}{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.73,0.13,0.13}{##1}}}
\@namedef{PY@tok@dl}{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.73,0.13,0.13}{##1}}}
\@namedef{PY@tok@s2}{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.73,0.13,0.13}{##1}}}
\@namedef{PY@tok@sh}{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.73,0.13,0.13}{##1}}}
\@namedef{PY@tok@s1}{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.73,0.13,0.13}{##1}}}
\@namedef{PY@tok@mb}{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.40,0.40,0.40}{##1}}}
\@namedef{PY@tok@mf}{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.40,0.40,0.40}{##1}}}
\@namedef{PY@tok@mh}{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.40,0.40,0.40}{##1}}}
\@namedef{PY@tok@mi}{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.40,0.40,0.40}{##1}}}
\@namedef{PY@tok@il}{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.40,0.40,0.40}{##1}}}
\@namedef{PY@tok@mo}{\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.40,0.40,0.40}{##1}}}
\@namedef{PY@tok@ch}{\let\PY@it=\textit\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.25,0.50,0.50}{##1}}}
\@namedef{PY@tok@cm}{\let\PY@it=\textit\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.25,0.50,0.50}{##1}}}
\@namedef{PY@tok@cpf}{\let\PY@it=\textit\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.25,0.50,0.50}{##1}}}
\@namedef{PY@tok@c1}{\let\PY@it=\textit\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.25,0.50,0.50}{##1}}}
\@namedef{PY@tok@cs}{\let\PY@it=\textit\def\PY@tc##1{\textcolor[rgb]{0.25,0.50,0.50}{##1}}}

\def\PYZbs{\char`\\}
\def\PYZus{\char`\_}
\def\PYZob{\char`\{}
\def\PYZcb{\char`\}}
\def\PYZca{\char`\^}
\def\PYZam{\char`\&}
\def\PYZlt{\char`\<}
\def\PYZgt{\char`\>}
\def\PYZsh{\char`\#}
\def\PYZpc{\char`\%}
\def\PYZdl{\char`\$}
\def\PYZhy{\char`\-}
\def\PYZsq{\char`\'}
\def\PYZdq{\char`\"}
\def\PYZti{\char`\~}
% for compatibility with earlier versions
\def\PYZat{@}
\def\PYZlb{[}
\def\PYZrb{]}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\section*{}

\begin{Verbatim}[commandchars=\\\{\}]
\PY{c+cp}{\PYZsh{}}\PY{c+cp}{include} \PY{c+cpf}{\PYZlt{}iostream\PYZgt{}}

\PY{k+kt}{int} \PY{n+nf}{main}\PY{p}{(}\PY{p}{)}\PY{p}{\PYZob{}}
    \PY{n}{std}\PY{o}{:}\PY{o}{:}\PY{n}{cout} \PY{o}{\PYZlt{}}\PY{o}{\PYZlt{}} \PY{l+s}{\PYZdq{}}\PY{l+s}{Hello, World! \PYZlt{}\PYZlt{} std::endl;}
    \PY{k}{return} \PY{l+m+mi}{0}\PY{p}{;}
\PY{p}{\PYZcb{}}
\end{Verbatim}

\end{document}
```

### Background details

I have identified that the problem is related to the verbatim environment. In a related question, [Doesn't the verbatim environment work with the standalone class?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/308638),  Steven B. Segletes suggests that the `verbatimbox` should be used, but in the present example, that does not seem to work, probably because the class `fancyvrb` is also used.

Further [Zarko](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/307984) suggests setting `varwidth` and writes,

> Also work with option varwidth. Both options enable to show verbatim environments and as well as displayed math. This is not special described in standalone manual, but seems that for text elements/environments, which normally occupy whole text line, it is obligatory to select appropriate standalone's options.

However, I'm not sure how to do this.

### Python code for the MWE

```python
from pygments import highlight
from pygments.lexers import CppLexer
from pygments.formatters import LatexFormatter

code = """
#include <iostream>

int main(){
    std::cout << "Hello, World! << std::endl;
    return 0;
}

"""

str_latex = highlight(code, CppLexer(), LatexFormatter(full=True))

with open("hello.tex", mode="wt",encoding="utf8") as f:
    f.write(str_latex)


# Open hello.tex and change 
# from
#  \documentclass{article}
# to 
#  \documentclass[preview]{standalone}
# then run
# pdflatex hello.tex
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know how to make this automatically generated by `pygments`, but if you change the documentclass to

```latex
\documentclass[varwidth, preview]{standalone}
```

and then change the environment from `Verbatim` to `BVerbatim` (see manual of `fancyverb` package, page 17) it works:

[image]